# How does meterpreter STDAPI bypass window's webcam restriction's settings

Tags: windows, metasploit, meterpreter

How does the stdapi commands 'webcam_snap' and 'webcam_stream' in meterpreter session bypass webcam restrictions/privacy settings on windows? I want to know how one could replicate this for prevention and analysis or just how it works in general.

Comment: What do you mean by "Webcam restrictions on Windows"? Are you referring to Windows 10's Privacy Settings?

Comment: Yes edited to make more clear.

Comment: And did you verify that Meterpreter is actually able to create a picture of the webcam and doesn't just return e.g. a black image?

Comment: Yes, I've tested on fully updated windows machine, even with windows defender running it bypasses.

Comment: Alright. It might be that the Windows 10 Privacy Settings only count for "installed" applications, not any process. Otherwise you'd see every executable found on your PC in there. Or at least a set of programs that Windows 10 is aware of. But that's just me guessing.

Comment: Interesting, when I test with opencv in various languages it's unable to take a snapshot or stream with "Allow apps to access your camera" turned off. I assumed it was because of a bypass or something of that nature.

Comment: [This page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4468232/windows-10-camera-microphone-and-privacy) specifically mentions controls over "Microsoft Store Apps", so it might be possible that other executables are just ignored, or based on what Windows recognizes.